# Получить элементы по индексам в Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

В наличии имеется двумерный тензор tensor размерности 4х3 тензор индексов indices. Необходимо получить двумерный массив modified_tensor, что и массив tensor (более понятно в примере). Как это сделать циклами понятно, но нужно реализовать срезами. Типа такого tensor[indices] - это, естественно не работает)

```
import torch
tensor = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 5],
                       [4, 6, 8],
                       [12, 87, 23],
                       [13, 31, 27]])

indices = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1, 0])   
modified_tensor = torch.tensor([
                               [1, 5, 2, 1],
                               [4, 8, 6, 4],
                               [12, 23, 87, 12],
                               [13, 27, 31, 13]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
modified_tensor = tensor[:, indices]
```